# Sqoop import. how many max mapper could be executed

Tags: sqoop

How many max number of mapper could be executed in Sqoop import. Also, while importing using sqoop is there any case where reducer is running.

Comment: `Sqoop` may have reducer based on requirement. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

1.**How many max number of mapper could be executed in Sqoop import?**

> > Increasing the number of  mappers will lead to a higher number of
> >     concurrent data transfer tasks, *'which can'* result in faster job
> >     completion.
> >
> > It won’t always lead to faster job completion. While increasing the
> >     number of mappers, there is a point at which you will fully saturate
> >     your database. Increasing the number of mappers beyond this point
> >     won’t lead to faster job completion; in fact, it will have the
> >     opposite effect as your database server spends more time doing context
> >     switching rather than serving data.
> >
> > The optimal number of mappers depends on many variables:
> >
> > 1.Database type.
> >
> > 2.Hardware that is used for your database server.
>
> 3. Impact to other requests that your database needs to serve.
>
>    > Start with small number of mappers for your  to find the optimal
>    >     degree of parallelism for your environment and use case.

2.**Also, while importing using sqoop is there any case where reducer is 
running.**

> Reducers are needed for aggregation.Number of reducers for sqoop is 0,
>   since it is merely a job running a MAP only job that dumps data into
>   HDFS. We are not aggregating anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Max Number of mappers

It can be any number, but it should be set based on data, resource and desired parallelism. More mapper is does not mean more performance.

> is there any case where reducer is running

**Yes** - there are special circumstances, when sqoop job may have reducer.

One such condition is [documented here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports).

```
sqoop export \
    -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=2
    -Dpgbulkload.bin="/usr/local/bin/pg_bulkload" \
    -Dpgbulkload.input.field.delim=$'\t' \
    -Dpgbulkload.check.constraints="YES" \
    -Dpgbulkload.parse.errors="INFINITE" \
    -Dpgbulkload.duplicate.errors="INFINITE" \
    --connect jdbc:postgresql://pgsql.example.net:5432/sqooptest \
    --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.PGBulkloadManager \
    --table test --username sqooptest --export-dir=/test -m 2
```

> `mapred.reduce.tasks` - Number of reduce tasks for staging. The
>   default value is 1. Each tasks do staging in a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop jobs use **`4`** map tasks by default. It can be modified by passing either `-m` or `--num-mappers` argument to the job. There is no maximum limit on number of mappers set by Sqoop, but the total number of concurrent connections to the database is a factor to consider. Read more about Controlling Parallelism in Sqoop [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism).

If the table does not have a **Primary Key** defined and the `--split-by` argument is not provided to the sqoop command, the number of mappers should be explicitly set to **`1`**.

Sqoop jobs do not have any **reduce** task.