# Does Sqoop use Reducer?

Tags: database, hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

Does Sqoop run reducer if there is a join/aggregation performed in the select query given with a `--query` parameter? Or is there any case in Sqoop where both mappers and reducers run?

[Documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) specifies that each map task will need to execute a copy of the query, with results partitioned by bounding conditions inferred by Sqoop.

```
$ sqoop import \
  --query 'SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b on (a.id == b.id) WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
  --split-by a.id --target-dir /user/foo/joinresults
```

In the example above, how does the `JOIN` take place where the table is first partitioned using `$CONDITIONS`?

Comment: seems like a interview question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join/Computation will be executed on RDBMS and its result will be used by mapper to transfer to HDFS.
No reducer is involved

With `--query` parameter, you need to specify the `--split-by` parameter with the column that should be used for slicing
your data into multiple parallel map tasks. This parameter usually automatically defaults to
the primary key of the main table

$CONDITIONS will be automatically substituted this placeholder with the generated conditions specifying which slice of data to transfer

Comment: So, does this mean data is partitioned per mapper using `--split-by` **after** the `JOIN` is performed by the database?

Comment: If this is the case then query executions would be the bottle-neck and only data transfer to Hadoop will be in parallel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199789/sqoop-import-how-many-max-mapper-could-be-executed/43270927#43270927 ..u may get ur answer here

Comment: Yeah, but mappers only come into the picture once the data to be exported is `sliced` and ready to be shipped to HDFS. And this process has to **wait** for `aggregates` to be performed by DB.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular command, the `sqoop` does not use reducer.
However there are cases, when `sqoop` do use `reducer`. Check the below example taken from [document here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_pg_bulkload_connector).

```
$ sqoop export \
    -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=2
    -Dpgbulkload.bin="/usr/local/bin/pg_bulkload" \
    -Dpgbulkload.input.field.delim=$'\t' \
    -Dpgbulkload.check.constraints="YES" \
    -Dpgbulkload.parse.errors="INFINITE" \
    -Dpgbulkload.duplicate.errors="INFINITE" \
    --connect jdbc:postgresql://pgsql.example.net:5432/sqooptest \
    --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.PGBulkloadManager \
    --table test --username sqooptest --export-dir=/test -m 2
```

Comment: so, is this the only case or there are others as well?

Comment: As you must have realized that sqoop is a collection of tools and here sqoop's way of working is defined by a `connector`. There can always be a new connector written which has a reducer in its lifecycle. As of now I know this one which bundled as standard feature, but a custom code can always bring in a reducer depending on the design.